# In-universe, was Eddie and Reed’s song ‘The Touch’ plagiarised by Transformers after Boogie Nights?

Tags: soundtrack, transformers, transformers-generation-1

In *[Boogie Nights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boogie_Nights)*, [Eddie Adams and Reed Rothchild record a song called ‘The Touch’](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eYAAbbuEpnw). The recording session takes place in March 1983. Eddie is later unable to pay to obtain the studio tapes.

In real life, [the song](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Touch_(Stan_Bush_song)) was written by Stan Bush, initially for the movie *Cobra* before being included on the soundtrack for *The Transformers: The Movie*. As both these movies were released in 1986, presumably the song wasn’t yet written by March 1983.

In [the Boogie Nights cinematic universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dirk_Diggler_Story), did the studio owner go on to sell Eddie and Reed’s composition to Stan Bush, perhaps to recoup the studio fees they never paid? Did they go on to see their song included on the soundtrack to [the greatest motion picture ever made](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Transformers:_The_Movie)?

(I realise the movie itself doesn’t detail this, but is there perhaps a novelisation? A continuing comic series? Some comments by the director? Anything in *The Dirk Diggler Story*?)

Alternatively, does the *Transformers* history of the Boogie Nights cinematic universe differ from our own? Did *The Transformers: The Movie* come out, say, five years earlier? (With a bold, forward-looking soundtrack that kicked off the power ballads trend of the 1980s and inspired Eddie and Reed to cover its lead track?) Did Eddie have any Transformers posters on his bedroom wall? Or — almost unimaginably — did the Transformers never even come to be?